# check if user is logged in with JQuery rating and alert you have to be logged in if not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Check if the user is logged in or not, If the user is logged in alert with thanks for rating, and if not alert with please log in to rate

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#demo2 .stars").click(function ()  {

        $.post( "rate.php",{rate:$(this).val(), vid_id : 
       $vid_result['vid_id']}, function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        //JSON.parse(d);

         if(d.status && d.trim(status) == 'active'){

          alert('Thanks For Rating');

          }
          else if(d.status && d.trim(status) == 'inactive'){

          alert('You have to be logged in to rate'); 

         }

        },"json");
      });
    });
 </script>
```

This query uses this php bellow in order to alert the user that he/she has successfully rated. I have managed to insert rating only if the user is logged in with PHP and not insert rating if he/she is not logged in. However how can i fix the JQuery to alert the user with the appropriate message based on if the user is logged in or not?

```
 // this page is rate.php

 <?php

  include 'core/init.php'; 

 if (isset($_POST['rate']) && !empty($_POST['rate'])) {
  if(isset($session_user_id)){
  $rate = sanitize($_POST['rate']);
   $vidid = sanitize($_POST['vid_id']);
 // check if user has already rated
   $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `rating` WHERE `rater_id`='" . 
  $session_user_id."' AND  `video_id` = '".$vidid."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     $sql = "UPDATE rating SET `rate` = '$rate' WHERE `rater_id`='" . $session_user_id . "' AND `video_id` = '".$vidid."'";
      if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {        }
    echo $row['id'];
} else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `rating` (`video_id`, `rater_id`, `rate`) VALUES ('$vidid' ,'$session_user_id', '$rate')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     //success
    json_encode(array('status'=>'active'));
    }else
    echo "fail";
}
}else{
     //not logged in
     json_encode(array('status'=>'inactive'));
  }
  }

?>
```

Comment: In your php, you should return their status, instead of your `"0"`/`"fail"`/`"you have to be logged in to rate"`. ie. `echo json_encode(array("status"=>"active");` / `echo json_encode(array("status"=>"inactive");`. Then in your `$.post()::success`, check the status, ie. `if(d.status == 'active') { //say thank you, and check the rating } else if (d.status == 'inactive' ) { // tell them to login first }`

Comment: @Sean Hi thank you for replying, however where do i have to echo the json_encode(array... with the status at?

Comment: @Sean I have edited the post and added what you recommended for me, however it is still not working are there other ways i can deal with this issue?

Comment: you forgot to parse the json object.

Answer (score 0):

rate.php:

echo the json encoded array at both places

```
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'active'));
```

in jquery post:
remove `d.trim(status)` instead do

```
d.status && d.status == 'active'
```

Comment: I have parse the json object and updated my answer, it still not working, i do appreciate your help tho.

Comment: which user are you trying? the one that is logged in and has already rated or the one which is logged in but has not rated?

Comment: i am trying on the one that is not logged in but is trying to rate.

Comment: Have you included the correct address to your php file and is the request getting there?

Comment: One thing about the isset tho, if you have declared the $session_user_id variable and even if its empty or has no user id it will still evaluate to true you should make sure that the $session_user_id variable is only generated for logged in user.

Comment: Yes the request is getting there, however its not using a different php file its all in the same php file thats why the address is empty

Comment: Yes the $_session_user_id only generated if users are logged in        if(logged_in() == true){
  
  $session_user_id = user_id_from_username($_SESSION['username']);
  $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id', 'username','password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'avatar');
  
    }

Comment: I wasn't feeling good about the request and response on the same page so i did a quick test and found out something.. console.log(d) and check the console.

Comment: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: But don't parse the response. remove the JSON.parse(d) part ofcourse it will throw errors in this case.

Comment: It send back the whole page...  i guess thats where the problem is?

Comment: yeah that's it i am looking for a solution.

Comment: The jquery docs say that if you want to get only json in response then there is an extra argument for post, like $.post("url",data,success, dataType). the dataType part is "json". try that.

Comment: Is my formatting correct, please have a look at my edited post

Comment: No. At the end of post function $.post( "",{rate:$(this).val()}, function(d) {
        console.log(d);

         if(d.status && d.trim(status) == 'active'){

          alert('Thanks For Rating');

          }
          else if(d.status && d.trim(status) == 'inactive'){

          alert('You have to be logged in to rate'); 

         }

        },"json");

Comment: Can you move your php logic to another page. It will make things alot cleaner and easier.

Comment: The problem is that i would need the $vidid = sanitize($vid_result['vid_id']); which is in the current page, except if can be passed the the jquery too. can it?

Comment: yeah ofcourse why not. put everything in your data object.. { rate : "some val" , vid_id : $vidid }

Comment: see the answer.